# how to make a reusable AMI of a system that is already a member of a windows domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have a "golden image" server that is set up, all packages installed and updated, and its joined to a windows domain.  We have to join the system to the domain first, because some of the packages are dependent upon domain resource.

I've taken an AMI of this golden image system, but if I spin up a instance from this AMI, I just put a copy of the same server (same hostname, etc) on our VPC.  I want to use this AMI as a golden image to spin up 40 or more instances, all identical except for hostname, and still on the domain.

Please tell me how I can make an AMI of an instance that is on an AD domain, but have it spin up with a different hostname (still a member of the domain).  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of an option in a form of User Data.
When you launch an instance you have an option to put User Data scripts (Powershell\Batch in Windows)(Bash in linux),
In this scripts you can try to change the instance name,
in the User Data just put

```
<powershell>
Rename-computer –computername “Current_Computer_Name” –newname “New_Computer_Name_X” –domaincredential domain\user –force –restart
</powershell>
```

Where you are calling the RunInstance (AWS SDK for .NET\Java\Python\etc.)
Just increment the X on "New_Computer_Name_X" by 1 every time you start a new instance.

[Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud -> User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html)